# NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

Tags: objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

Hi I am a trying to use a custom delegate alongside the NSFetchedResultsController delegate but I am finding if I implement my XMLParserDelegate the the fetch results controller does not populate the UITableview but if I remove the XMLParserDelegate everything populates OK.

I seem to be able to get one or the other working but not both together any ideas?

I am new to iphone programming :(

```
@interface FirstViewController : UITableViewController     <XMLParserDelegate,NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

{
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
}
```

Comment: Standard fetchrequest works fine for example NSArray *myarray = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; Its just when using the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

Comment: Which specific method is not working? What do you want to accomplish with it?

Comment: Thanks for replying the NSFetchResultsController is not working i seem to get callback from my XMLParser delegate saying i have finished and here is the array of objects. I have not connected the array to the core data yet as am using test data to fill the core data and then doing an NSFetch on this it then does not populate the uitableview I probably should include a bit more code here for clarity ,I'll try to do that soon

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect the data from your XML parser to the fetched results controller.

When the parser is finished, insert the objects into your managed object context and save, then maybe reload the table view. The parsed results should now be displayed.

Comment: all I seemed to need was `[self.tableView reloadData]; // Why did I need this?` oh I had an issue with the delegate its all working fine now, thanks for your help